# MVC application and IE7 browser and Network issue

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-2, networking, pdf

I have a .net MVC application which opens up the result of a Quiz as a pdf in the browser. The problem is It works well and good in DEV box, QA box and OPS (in both IE7 and firefox browsers) which are in with in the firewall. but in the production (live) which is out of firewall, I get an error "File couldnot be downloaded" in IE7 browser. Initially I thought it might be a firewall issue but to my suprise it works well and good in  Firefox browser. My assumption is
1. If it works in firefox but not in IE7 in PRODUCTION, certainly there would not be a firewall issue.
2. The code and settings both in OPS and PROD are same. so no blame on code.
3. The file is not even downloaded to the %temp% directory, means IE cant access the file/ resource.(but when using Firefox the file gets downloaded and opens in browser).
4. If I say it is a problem of IE7 , then it shouldnot work in DEV and QA, but it works.

I browsed extensively on Internet and tried to install/ uninstall versions of Adobe and installing plug in for IE. but nothing changed.

Any suggestions would be really helpful!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem to be a security setting checked in application firewall. unchecking the security settings for Field format makes it work..

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is a security setting in IE and that your DEV/QA servers are in a different security zone than production.  You should be able to see which security zone a site is in by looking at the status bar in IE.  Then you can compare the security settings between the two.  I've seen problems like this in the past related to saving files from secure sites (https).

Comment: Security settings between the two are same. I think some authentication request sent from IE is being rejected by the Servers in PROD.. but dont know what exactly it is.